# Can I buy coach tickets to central London at Luton airport?

Tags: tickets, buses, ltn

I suspect the answer is yes, but I'm looking for confirmation and a quick Google search didn't turn up anything definitive.

I'm flying into London Luton tomorrow morning and want to take a coach to Victoria station. I am unable to buy a ticket online (my bank is being obstinate and not letting the transaction through), so I would like to know if I can buy an easyBus or National Express or Green Line ticket from a kiosk at the airport or the driver him/herself.

Comment: Perhaps a call to the bank is in order. It's possible they blocked your card entirely and you are in for a nasty surprise when you finish a lovely pint of Guinness and can't pay for it.

Comment: Second @chx it may be the foreign transaction and you may need to alert your bank to your travel plans, as my VISA requires (although Amex says not to worry, it knows when I travel :-)

Comment: @chx, Dorothy -- I've been traveling for a year now, though, and my bank actually told me to stop adding travel alerts because they get the picture, and they can only modify my card a certain number of times. And I just withdrew money from an ATM here in Bulgaria so the card's ok, just not for purchasing bus tickets apparently. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely possible at the airport, if you've not bought online (although it can be more expensive).

Source: I've done it myself with easyBus, and they charged me more than I expected; from then on I bought online in advance.

Second source: [easyBus](http://www.easybus.com/en/london-luton/luton-to-from-victoria/luton-airport-bus-station):

> Luton Airport to London Buses Pick Up/Drop Off Directions
>
> After collection of luggage pass through the Customs Area. You will emerge in the arrival hall.
>
> easyBus counter is straight ahead on left hand side for any assistance otherwise if you have online tickets, please proceed straight to the coach station just outside the exit.
>
> Our Luton to London service is operated by National Express and departs from Stop 10, right in front of the terminal.

Comment: I confirm this, I have done it as well

Comment: Yep, found it. There's a Nat'l Express desk immediately past the sign for bus/train/taxi. A little past that are automated kiosks for Nat'l Express. And opposite the door leading to the bus terminal are a collection of ticket desks. Also the bus stops are labelled with letters, not numbers, so I'm not sure what the quite from easyBus refers to. The electronic board listing upcoming departures makes it a moot point, though